# Count occurrences per entry in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following kind of dataframe (this is simplified example):

```
id = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4")
bank = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "c", "a", "c")
df = data.frame(id, bank)
df

  id bank
1  1    a
2  1    b
3  1    c
4  2    b
5  3    b
6  3    c
7  4    a
8  4    c
```

In this dataframe you can see that for some ids there are multiple banks, i.e. for `id==1`, `bank=c(a,b,c)`.

The information I would like to extract from this dataframe is the overlap between id's within different banks and the count.

So for example for bank `a`: bank `a` has two persons (unique ids): 1 and 4. For these persons, I want to know what other banks they have

- For person 1: bank b and c
- For person 4: bank c

the total amount of other banks: 3, for which, b = 1, and c = 2.

So I want to create as output a sort of overlap table as below:

```
bank overlap amount
a    b       1
a    c       2
b    a       1
b    c       2
c    a       2
c    b       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to get a result, so I post it. Not as sexy as Ronak Shahs but same result.

```
id = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4")
    bank = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "c", "a", "c")
    df = data.frame(id, bank)

df$bank <- as.character(df$bank)

resultlist <- list()
dflist <- split(df, df$id)

for(i in 1:length(dflist)) {
    if(nrow(dflist[[i]]) < 2) {
        resultlist[[i]] <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2))
    } else {
        resultlist[[i]] <- as.data.frame(t(combn(dflist[[i]]$bank, 2))) 
    }
}
result <-  setNames(data.table(rbindlist(resultlist)), c("bank", "overlap"))

result %>%
    group_by(bank, overlap) %>%
    summarise(amount = n())

  bank  overlap amount
  <fct> <fct>    <int>
1 a     b            1
2 a     c            2
3 b     c            2
```

Comment: keep in mind that you need strings, not factors, otherwise a conversion from matrix to data.frame will destroy your structure -> to be honest, I don´t know why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be `full_join`

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df, df, by = "id") %>%     
      filter(bank.x != bank.y) %>%
      dplyr::count(bank.x, bank.y) %>%
      select(bank = bank.x, overlap = bank.y, amount = n)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  bank  overlap amount
#  <fct> <fct>    <int>
#1 a     b            1
#2 a     c            2
#3 b     a            1
#4 b     c            2
#5 c     a            2
#6 c     b            2
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `data.table`:

```r
df = data.frame(id = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4"), 
                bank = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "c", "a", "c"))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(bank = rep(bank, (.N-1L):0L), 
              overlap = bank[(sequence((.N-1L):1L) + rep(1:(.N-1L), (.N-1L):1))]), 
                 by=id][, 
                        .N, by=.(bank, overlap)]
#>    bank overlap N
#> 1:    a       b 1
#> 2:    a       c 2
#> 3:    b       c 2
#> 4: <NA>       b 1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Please note that you have `b` for `id==2` which is not overlapping with other values. If you don't want that in the final product, just apply `na.omit()` on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to cover both banks in both the directions? Since a -> b is same as b -> a in this case here. We can use `combn` and create combinations of unique `bank` taken 2 at a time, find out `length` of common `id` found in the combination.

```
as.data.frame(t(combn(unique(df$bank), 2, function(x) 
     c(x, with(df, length(intersect(id[bank == x[1]], id[bank == x[2]])))))))

#  V1 V2 V3
#1  a  b  1
#2  a  c  2
#3  b  c  2
```

**data**

```
id = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4")
bank = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "c", "a", "c")
df = data.frame(id, bank, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. You are right, a -> b is the same as b -> a, so those are double and do not need to be cover both. however, if i try your solution, i get the following error: Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor

Comment: @wdp oops, sorry you have factors, which I converted to characters. Can you read the data using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` ? Or do `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)`